# Raspberry Pi Zero - Turned into a Virtual Mouse is not working properly on Windows 10 build 1809 (Cursor is snapping back to the left upper corner)

Tags: c++, windows, raspberry-pi, windows-10, raspberry-pi-zero

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero which i have turned it into a virtual keyboard and virtual mouse. I've done it using this amazing (thank you, SeongTae Jeong!) repo on github - [rasp_vusb](https://github.com/stjeong/rasp_vusb). To shortly summarize how it works:

1. You connect the PI Zero to a different computer via an USB cable and connect it to the Internet with an ethernet cable.
2. After connecting it to the computer it creates 3 new devices in the Device Manager (Windows):

   - Human Interface Devices

     - Usb Input Device
   - Keyboards

     - HID Keyboard Device
   - Mice and other pointing devices

     - HID-compliant mouse  (Absolute position + buttons)
     - HID-compliant mouse  (Relative position + wheel)
3. There is a "server" running on the PI zero (code found in the rasp_vusb_server on the repo), which accepts your commands and then sends them as a mouse commands or as a keyboard commands to the device you are connected via USB.
4. You can send commands from a *different* computer to the PI zero (the server) by connecting to it's IP and sending the proper data. You can use the already built in program in the repo i provided which is located in the map *InputController*

Now this works ***perfectly*** on Windows 10 build 1803 and build 1903. It also works on Mac but I haven't tested the keyboard function on a Mac. The weird problem occurs when the Pi Zero is connected to a Windows 10 (pro or home) build 1809.

The **keyboard** commands, **relative mouse** commands (Meaning: move the cursor +50 pixel to the right from the position you are on atm) and **mouse button** (clicking) commands are working **fine**, but the **absolute mouse** commands (Meaning: move the cursor at X = 50, Y = 50 on the screen) and **wheel** commands do **not work** - ***The cursor keeps snapping at the upper left corner (coordinates, X=0, Y=0)***.

I tried this on many different computers and Windows builds, different Monitors (some had touch screens, others didn't), different Pi zeros. **The problem only occurs on Windows 10 build 1809**.
I tried searching on the web about similar problems but all the answers lead to some touchscreen problems, but as I said in my case the touch screen is not the problem, as it works on different builds.

(**I'm not actually sure if this has anything to do with the problem, because this is the code/command we send to the PI zero and then the PI zero sends it to the connected device**)
I started digging in the code and i found that when sending an absolute mouse command you send a byte array with a length of 15. I will explain it with an example for better understanding:

Let's say you want to send the an **absolute mouse command**, that you want to move the cursor to **X=50** and **Y=100** on the screen. As it's stated in the readme file in the repo you have to make some calculation depending on your screen resolution. So let's say we have a **1920x1080** resolution. Then we send X=(50 * 32767 / 1920) = 853 and Y=(100 * 32767 / 1080) = 3033. Then you have to call a function `byte[] ConvertToMouseCommands("853 3033")`. It's found in the repo in the ***InputController/MouseDevice.cs*** or ***Demo/MouseDevice.cs***. This function translates the numbers to a byte array like so: (EDIT*) I will put next to it the byte array that is created when sending a relative mouse command like (X=+50, Y=+50) for comparison.

```
[0] = 11  <- Packet length (15 - 4)             [0] = 7 (11-4)                    
[1] = 0                                         [1] = 0
[2] = 0                                         [2] = 0
[3] = 0                                         [3] = 0
[4] = 7   <- 7 means absolute command           [4] = 6   <- 6 means relative commands
[5] = 85  <- (xPos & 0xff)                      [5] = 0                     
[6] = 3   <- (xPos & 0xff00) >> 8)              [6] = 50  <- xPos (Just xPos!) you can only send +-127 
[7] = 217 <- (yPos & 0xff)                      [7] = 50  <- yPos (Just yPos!) you can only send +-127 
[8] = 11  <- (yPos & 0xff00) >> 8)              [8] = 0
[9] = 0                                         [9] = 0
[10] = 0                                        [10] = 0
[11] = 0
[12] = 0
[13] = 0
[14] = 0
```

These are the byte arrays we send to the PI zero. When the PI zero receives them, it uses two function (depending if it's relative mouse command or absolute mouse command) to send them further.
The two functions are `void MouseDevice::SendRelative(int fd, char *mouseInput, int keyLen)` and `void MouseDevice::SendAbsolute(int fd, char *mouseInput, int keyLen)`. They can be found in the repo in the ***rasp_vusb_server/MouseDevice.cpp***. I don't want to paste the code here because this post is already long enough, but essentially they send the X coordinate, the Y coordinate, if the buttons are clicked or if the wheel on the mouse has rotated - It seems pretty straight forward to me.

As i said, the code works perfectly on other Windows builds, it just fails on the build 1809. I honestly don't even know how to start debugging something like this. Did something changed in that build - Should i send the bytes somewhat different?  Is there some magical solution like disabling a driver or something (wishful thinking)? Should i try even older Windows 10 builds to see if it works?

I would be very thankful for any information that you can provide.
Thank you!

Comment: Those byte arrays are probably USB HID packets. See what a USB sniffer can tell you.

Comment: This sounds like something you should ask the github repo owner or possibly Microsoft. Also, if it works on the latest Windows build, then why not just use that? Is there a reason that you have to use 1809 specifically?

Comment: Someprogrammerdude I see, thank you!
@Botje Thank you, you have given me some hope! I've installed a sniffer and I found out that there are always two HID packages sent on both Build 1903 and 1809. The first one is the correct one with the coordinates and the second one is always coordinates at X=0 and Y=0. Although the former build accepts it, it may confuse the previous one. I will try to modify the code so the second one won't be sent and see where that takes me.

Comment: @Frodyne If the code modification won't work, I will try to contact the Owner of the repo or (hopefully) Microsoft. I'm reluctant to just use the latest build, because perhaps in the future another build will fail. So, I would like to fix this bug now. Thanks for the answer!